# Python subprocess not working in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, subprocess

I need to get a few processes executed via Subprocess in Python in Google Cloud Function.

```
import subprocess
import os
def hello_world(request):
    print(subprocess.call(["echo", "hello","world"]))
```

Expected output:
hello world

Actual output:
0

Does google functions block the execution of subprocess or do I need to receive the output in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `subprocess`. If you want to return the output from your subprocess call, and not the exit code, you must use `subprocess.check_output()` (and return the result):

```py
import subprocess

def hello_world(request):
    return subprocess.check_output(["echo", "'hello world'"])
```

However if you're just trying to return a string, this is unnecessary and the following will suffice:

```py
def hello_world(request):
    return "hello world"
```